# tfRecords shown faulty in TF2

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, object-detection-api, tfrecord, tensorflow2

I have a couple of own tfrecord file made by myself.
They are working perfectly in tf1, I used them in several projects.
However if i want to use them in Tensorflow Object Detection API with tf2 (running the model_main_tf2.py script), I see the following in tensorboard:

[tensorboard images tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnEB9.png)

It totally masses up the images.
(Running the /work/tfapi/research/object_detection/model_main.py script or even legacy_train and they looks fine)
Is tf2 using different kind of encoding in tfrecords?
Or what can cause such results?

Comment: Same problem here, hopefully the problem is just for visualization, I noticed that eval images are working fine.

Comment: Yupp, seems everything working fine except the visualization.