# saturated contrast and low brightness in tensorboard when training TF2 object_detection API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I'm trying to fine-tune an efficient det model. Here is a recap of what I've done:

- [download coco dataset 2014](https://cocodataset.org/#download)
- convert to tfrecord with [a script from tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py)
- download efficientDet D0 from [official model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)
- edit pipeline.config (batch_size: 1, sync_replicas: false, replicas_to_aggregate: 1, fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection", use_bfloat16: false) and adjust the paths.
- clone [github.com/tensorflow/models.git](https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git), `docker-compose run object_detection`.
- inside the container:

```
python models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/pipeline.config \
    --model_dir=foo/model/ \
    --alsologtostderr
```

My problem is that as seen in tensorboard (ie after data preprocessing), contrast is maxed out (or sometimes not maxed, but still way too high), and brightness is often too low:
[image]

I checked the content of the tfrecords with https://github.com/sulc/tfrecord-viewer, the colors are fine.
I tried on another machine with a different nvidia GPU model, same problem.

Any idea where the problem could come from? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I'm not the first one to encounter this problem: this question is probably about the same issue, even if with less details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340690/tfrecords-shown-faulty-in-tf2

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 2):

this seems to be a visualization issue, and not a training issue. It can be solved by changing the normalization from (-1,1) to (0,1).

follow these changes in the code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/9019